# Indices on composite primary key

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, rdbms

I googled this a lot many times but I didn't get the exact explanation for the same.

I am working on a complex database structures (in Oracle 10g) where I hardly have a primary key on one single column except for the static tables.

Now my question is consider a composite primary key ID (`LXI, VCODE, IVID, GHID`). Since it's a primary key, Oracle will provide a default index.

Will I get ONE (system generated) single index for the primary key itself or for its sub-columns also?

Asking this because I am retrieving  data (around millions of records) based on individual columns as well. Now if system generates the indices for the individual columns as well. Why my query runs pretty faster than how it actually runs when I explicitly define indices for each individual column.

Please give a satisfactory answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the answer to this question is not difficult to verify for yourself, no?  Just check which indexes are created...

Comment: This is a good question.  It would be even better if it showed performance data for a query using the two different index structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary key is a non-NULL unique key.  In your case, the unique index has four columns, `LXI, VCODE, IVID  GHID` in the order of declaration.

If you have a condition on `VCODE` but not on `LXI`, then most databases would not use the index.  Oracle has a special type of index scan called the "skip scan", which allows for this very situation.  It is described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i51571).

I would expect an index skip scan to be a bit slower than an index range scan on individual columns.  However, which is better might also depend on the complexity of the `where` clause.  For instance, three equality conditions on `VCODE`, `IVID` and `GHID` connected by `AND` might be a great example for the skip scan.  And, such an index would cover the `WHERE` clause -- a great efficiency -- and better than one-column indexes.

As a note:  index skip scans were introduced in Oracle 9i, so they are available in Oracle 10.

Comment: Great..! Thanks for the explanation and documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will not generate index for individual column. it will generate a composite index 
first it will index on LXI
then next column like that it will be a tree structure.
if you search on 1st column of primary key it will use index to use index for second you have to combine it with the first column

```
ex : select where ...LXI=? will use index PK
     select where LXI=? and VCODE=? alse use pk
   but  select where  VCODE=?  will not use it (without LXI)
```

Comment: Mostly true, but Oracle is capable of performing skip index scanning as well for your last use case.

Comment: @sstan agreed but . "An index skip scan uses logical subindexes of a composite index. The database "skips" through a single index as if it were searching separate indexes. Skip scanning is beneficial if there are few distinct values in the leading column of a composite index and many distinct values in the nonleading key of the index."

Comment: @sstan if LXI is having large set of distinct values.